# How do you power an Amazon Echo Dot in the ceiling?

Tags: electrical, ceiling

I would like to mount Echo Dot units in the ceiling of all the rooms in my house in England. I have found a flush [ceiling mount](https://amzn.to/346NCsH) which will allow this.

[image: Echo Dot Ceiling Mount]

The rooms on the top floor are not a problem as I already have power in the loft. The rooms downstairs are more awkward, as I would need to power the Echo Dots under the floorboards to avoid percutaneous wires. To further complicate matters, the Echo Dot requires a "wall wart" transformer.

[image: Echo Dot Power Adapter]

I do already have power running under the floor in some locations. Could I spur off of this and install a socket under the floorboards? Would that be permissible in England?

What would be the best way to power the Echo Dots in the ceiling?

Comment: I would hardly say that a "wall wart" *complicates* things... if anything it *simplifies* things.  It puts the project in the very safe "low voltage" domain, which greatly eases the Code/safety requirements.  *In fact, that is why every modern electronic device comes with a "wall wart" - only the wall-wart touches AC mains, and that's a commodity item - so the rest of the device breezes through UL/BSI approval*.

Comment: Something [like this](https://www.techadvisor.com/test-centre/digital-home/best-usb-wall-sockets-3664216/) could solve the wall wart problem.

Comment: Older Echo Dots (Gen 1&2) used USB power but the newer generations do not. See the power connector type in the ceiling mount kit in photo 1 of the OP.

Answer (score 3):

### The wall-wart outputs low voltage. Take advantage of that.

I mean if you're going to mess about with AC mains in the UK , you have to follow all the electrical codes on that, and that is a bit byzantine for someone who just wants to install some smart-home gear.  (this comes up a lot).

However... The Amazon device is powered by a *low voltage wall-wart*.  Low voltage is very easy and safe to work with.

In fact, the kit you're buying includes the cable to do exactly that.  (mind you it's a third-party vendor presumably from the usual place, so who knows if it's compatible... but this is not a barrier.)

So the answer is simple: Plug the "wall wart" power supply into an AC mains plug in a workable location.  Then run low-voltage cable to the ceiling box.

If you can't make it happen with pre-made cables due to length, there is nothing wrong with cutting the pre-made cable in the middle and splicing in additional cable in between.  A readily available type of cable is regular 1.5mm2 "twin-and-earth", which will have a very heavy conductor (by low-voltage standards, anyway) which will assure the length doesn't cause voltage drop.

Comment: The mount just comes with an extension cable. I really don't want to plug the wall wart into an external socket - is there no other way around this?